# CMake combine multiple precompiled lib files to single target

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

We are using cmake and started using conan as a package manager.

Before conan however prebuild 3rd Party libs like GTest where added via
`find_package(GTest REQUIRED)`. (By adding custom find Scripts for each library find_package() was able to locate our prebuild third parties)

In the new conan way it's pretty easy to add 3rd parties to a library

```
add_library(myLib sources)
target_link_libraries(myLib PRIVATE GTEST::GTEST)
```

To achieve backwards compatibility i need to create a target with the name GTest::GTest from the find_package().
Now the question is how can i create a new target from the find_package() result?

I did try to create a new dummy target

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
add_library("GTest" "foo.cpp")
target_link_libraries("GTest" PUBLIC "${GTest_LIBRARIES}")
add_library("GTEST::GTEST" ALIAS GTest)
```

where foo.cpp is just an empty file.

when linking against the target GTEST::GTEST

this results in  a linker error `GTEST_1_0d.lib was not found`

How would you create a cmake target from prebuild binaries?
Could you help me out here?

**Edit**: Sorry for beeing unclear.
I do not want to touch legacy systems. Therefore Conan is not available on legacy systems.
The question is: How can I create targets from precompiled libraries that look exactly like Conan targets

Comment: Conan should have generated a `gtest::gtest` target for you already (I'm guessing you're using the [cmake_find_package generator](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake_find_package.html))?

Comment: You have to use the Conan generator `cmake_find_package`: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_find_package_generator.html which will create FindGTest.cmake with the target GTest::gtest.

Comment: sorry for being unclear. I edited my question above. Conan is not available on our legacy systems. I would like to have targets which look exactly like as if they were created by conan to be able to use these targets on Conan Systems and legacy systems

Answer (score 1):

> To achieve backwards compatibility i need to create a target with the name `GTest::GTest` from the `find_package()`. Now the question is how can i create a new target from the `find_package()` result?

As you say, the result of your call to `find_package(GTest)` is that `GTEST::GTEST` is created. So just write

```
add_library(GTest::GTest ALIAS GTEST::GTEST)
```

If you have code that needs to use the other name, no?

---

On the other hand:

> find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

If the result of your call to `find_package(GTest)` is the ancient built-in CMake module, then something like this might work:

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

# Not using Conan
if (NOT TARGET GTEST::GTEST)
  if (TARGET GTest::gtest)
    # CMake 3.20+ module in use
    add_library(GTEST::GTEST ALIAS GTest::gtest)
  elseif (TARGET GTest::GTest)
    # CMake 3.5+ module in use
    add_library(GTEST::GTEST ALIAS GTest::GTest)
  else ()
    add_library(GTEST::GTEST IMPORTED INTERFACE)
    target_include_directories(GTEST::GTEST INTERFACE "${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    target_link_libraries(GTEST::GTEST INTERFACE "${GTEST_LIBRARIES}")
  endif ()
endif ()
```

You can decide whether to add `GTest::gtest_main`, `GTest::Main`, or use `${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES}` in each of the three respective branches.